# How to retrieve multiple files using FTPClient object in java?

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I wanted to retrieve list of files (Say about 100 files) from a directory. 
I used `retrieveFileStream` method in java `FTPClient` object to get the files individually.

While retrieving the files, I am getting socket exception several times in between and I have a retry logic to overcome that.

The problem is each socket exception is causing a delay of 10 seconds, which eventually impacts my code performance.

I want to make code changes such that all the files to be retrieved in a
single function. I tried `listFiles` method in `FTPClient` object to get all the files in the particular directory. But my directory is having huge number of files (Say about 10000), which again impacts my code performance.
Is there any method to get list of files by providing the required file names list as input parameter? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make code changes such that all the files to be retrieved in a
>   single function. I tried `listFiles` method in `FTPClient` object to get all the files in the particular directory. But my directory is having huge number of files (Say about 10000), which again impacts my code performance.
>   Is there any method to get list of files by providing the required file names list as input parameter?

There's no better solution than the one you already have.

Of course, except for spliting the job to multiple threads.